# Upload attachment failure Facebook Attachment Upload API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to add an attachment to my message via facebook attachment upload API.

I am sending from a page (that I am an admin of) to a user that has sent message to my page.
Simple text messages are sent and also attachments as **type 'file'** is also working correctly. But when I put in **'image'** or **'audio'** as an attachment, the facebook sends response:

error: {
message: '(#100) Upload attachment failure.',
type: 'OAuthException',
code: 100,
error_subcode: 2018047,
fbtrace_id: 'AzfHWxf3AnikXiCCC-hYJOu'
}

Here is my code:

```
let messageData = {
          message: {
            attachment: {
              **type: "image"**,
              payload: {
                is_reusable: true,
                url: <url of the image>
              }
            }
          }
        }
        
let data = await axios.post(`https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/me/message_attachments?access_token=${accessToken}`, messageData)
```

Comment: Does the URL you are using return an appropriate Content-Type?

Comment: According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api, subcode->2018047 is "a common way to trigger this error is that the provided media type does not match type of file provided int the URL" In my case, it was an .jpeg extension in the URL which i had to rename to .jpg to get the API working. What was your actual media and the filename extension in the URI?

Answer (score 0):

Upload attachment failure. A common way to trigger this error is that the provided media type does not match type of file provided int the URL

from official [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api)

Answer (score 0):

For Golang, here's my copy-paste-ready example, see comments.

```golang
func UploadAttachment(dataBytes []byte, fileName string, contentType string) (string, error) {

    // Create a io.Reader to hold dataBytes and pass to http
    reader := bytes.NewReader(dataBytes)

    // Create a buffer and multipart writer
    var b bytes.Buffer
    multipartWriter := multipart.NewWriter(&b)

    // Define the structs
    type Payload struct {
        Reusable bool `json:"is_reusable"`
    }

    type Attachment struct {
        Type    string  `json:"type"`
        Payload Payload `json:"payload"`
    }

    type Message struct {
        Attachment Attachment `json:"attachment"`
    }
    msg := Message{
        Attachment: Attachment{
            Type: getTypeFromContentType(contentType),
            Payload: Payload{
                Reusable: true,
            },
        },
    }
    // Marshal the struct to JSON
    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(msg)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error marshalling to JSON:", err)
        return "", err
    }

    // Convert JSON bytes to string
    jsonString := string(jsonData)

    // Debug
    fmt.Println("Sending :" + jsonString)

    multipartWriter.WriteField("message", jsonString)
    multipartWriter.WriteField("access_token", os.Getenv("FACEBOOK_FAN_PERMANENT_TOKEN"))

    // Note ! formFileWriter is different from formFieldWriter, don't be lazy and reuse variable like (fw) will cause confusion from many "sample code"
    // Note ! w.CreateFormFile by default DO h.Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream"), but facebook requires the content-type matching or you get an error_subcode: 2018047
    // If you're using w.CreateFormFile and specify type="file" in the json payload, it's fine with facebook (no extra check). But when you specify type="image" in the json payload, here's why error_subcode: 2018047 kicks in.
    // Therefore, i copied from w.CreateFormFile (which is just a wrapper of CreatePart) and set the Content-Type to the correct one.
    // Manually create the form file part, setting the Content-Type explicitly
    // This concept also apply to whatsapp upload media

    h := make(textproto.MIMEHeader)
    h.Set("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf(`form-data; name="file"; filename="%s"`, fileName))
    h.Set("Content-Type", contentType) // << here
    formFileWriter, err := multipartWriter.CreatePart(h)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Write the binary data from reader to formFileWriter
    if _, err := io.Copy(formFileWriter, reader); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Close the writer
    multipartWriter.Close()

    // Create and send the request
    // I don't like to put access_token in the url (safer)
    url := os.Getenv("FACEBOOK_FAN_ENDPOINT") + "/message_attachments"

    // Debug
    fmt.Println("Posting to url " + url)

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, &b)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", multipartWriter.FormDataContentType()) // << multipart/form-data

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // Read the response body
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("error reading response body: %w", err)
    }

    // Debug Print the response body
    fmt.Println("Response Body:", string(body))

    // Check the response
    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("http not OK")
    }

    // Parse the JSON response
    var attachmentResp struct {
        ID string `json:"attachment_id"`
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(body, &attachmentResp); err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    // Assuming the response contains attachment_id
    if attachmentResp.ID != "" {
        return attachmentResp.ID, nil
    }

    return "", fmt.Errorf("no attachment ID found in response")

}

// Depends on contenType select typeField for the message payload
func getTypeFromContentType(contentType string) string { 
    var typeField = "file" // default as file
    switch contentType {
    case "image/jpeg":
        fallthrough
    case "image/png":
        typeField = "image"
    case "video/mp4":
        typeField = "video"
    case "text/plain":
        fallthrough
    case "application/pdf":
        fallthrough
    case "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint":
        fallthrough
    case "application/msword":
        fallthrough
    case "application/vnd.ms-excel":
        fallthrough
    case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document":
        fallthrough
    case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation":
        fallthrough
    case "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet":
        typeField = "file"
    }
    return typeField
}
```

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/message_attachments/
DO NOT See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/attachment-upload-api it's wrong about missing message_attachment(s) the final 's'
Also, payload is a "required" field, even if u send payload:{} is acceptable, but it's required. These were not stated in any document. :(

Comment: More details, if you send image to someone with type=file, he gets an attachment form of the image (not rendered) and the URL is https://cdn.fbsbx.com.
If you deal with content-type properly, the URL is https://www.facebook.com/messenger_media and image rendered properly at receiver's messenger.